# Youtube oembed 401 unauthorized for some videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, oembed

I'm currently facing a 401 Unauthorized error using the ruby gem "ruby-oembed" which use oEmbed and noembed libs.

I tried it directly with oembed and noembed and I got the following result

```
$> https://noembed.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xlegeyULX8
$> {"error":"401 Unauthorized","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xlegeyULX8"}
```

and you can try it with oembed [here](https://oembed.link/) with this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xlegeyULX8

I tried to check if the video is private or has different settings but I can't find any settings different with working cases.

Any idea why it could cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video you shared [`3xlegeyULX8`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xlegeyULX8) isn't embeddable, as [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)#[status.embeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) is `false` for this video (cf https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=3xlegeyULX8&fields=items(status/embeddable)&key=API_KEY)

> **status.embeddable**
>
> **boolean**
>
> This value indicates whether the video can be embedded on another website.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, didn't know about this API request to check the embed status :)